# How can I get file and line number where an error was returned?

Tags: rust, error-handling, runtime-error

Suppose I call function `f().unwrap()` which calls calls function `g`. The g function returns an `Error` wrapped in `Result`, and `f` propagates this error. Then I get the message that thread panicked at line where I called `f().unwrap()`.

I would like to know is the place where error was returned, i.e. where `g` returned error. This would be much more informative, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you return [`anyhow::Error`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/struct.Error.html), and you turn on the `backtrace` feature of `anyhow`, you can retrieve a backtrace from the error if you will set the environment variable `RUST_BACKTRACE` or `RUST_LIB_BACKTRACE` to `1`:

```rust
let error: anyhow::Error;
eprintln!("{}", error.backtrace());
```

Comment: @user643011 When you don't care what is your error type it is a fairly good use-case for `anyhow`. It's mostly not suited when you _do_ care what the error type is. Anyway, my answer is about anyhow. Other libraries may have similar facilities, or you may need to roll your own. In std you always need to roll your own (though perhaps this'll change in the future).

Comment: Makes sense. Not sure why my earlier comment got deleted by stackoverflow. I can't see it any more.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it but you have to collect and attach the info yourself:

With [anyhow](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow) you can add context to an error with the `context` method.

```rust
fn main() {
    f().unwrap();
}

fn f() -> Result<(), anyhow::Error> {
    g().map_err(|e| e.context(format!("at {}:{}:{}", file!(), line!(), column!())))?;
    Err(anyhow::anyhow!("some other error"))
}

fn g() -> Result<(), anyhow::Error> {
    Err(anyhow::anyhow!("oh noes"))
}
```

Or you can wrap the error in your own error type containing the info.

```rust
fn main() {
    f().unwrap();
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Error {
    file: &'static str,
    line: u32,
    column: u32,
    error: GError,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct GError;

fn f() -> Result<(), Error> {
    g().map_err(|e| Error {
        file: file!(),
        line: line!(),
        column: column!(),
        error: e,
    })
}

fn g() -> Result<(), GError> {
    Err(GError)
}
```

Comment: Yes you can store `file!()`, `line!()`, `column!()` as you please in your error.